# php get images only within body tags

Tags: php, parsing, loops, tags

I need to do the equivalent of this:

```
$tags2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$mybody = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
//if there's a body tag
foreach ($mybody as $bod){
            //loop through each img element
        foreach ($tags2 as $tag) {   
           echo  '<img src=' . $tag->getAttribute('src') . '/>';
           echo  "<br/>" . $tag->getAttribute('href') ; 
        }
}
```

Here's the context:

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://somewebsite.html');


$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $str);


$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->parseFile($str);
$tidy->cleanRepair();

if(!empty($tidy->errorBuffer)) {
        echo "The following errors or warnings occured:\n";
        echo $tidy->errorBuffer;
}
else {
    $str = $tidy;
}

$tags2 = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
$mybody = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
foreach ($mybody as $bod){
        foreach ($tags2 as $tag) {   
           echo  '<img src=' . $tag->getAttribute('src') . '/>';
           echo  "<br/>" . $tag->getAttribute('href') ; 
        }
}
```

^ outputs all the images on the page, in the header, on sidebars, etc. as well as the image in the body. I just want the image in the body. I tried a few other examples I saw on here using recursion but they were to get the styles or paragraph tags and I couldn't get them to retrieve image tag and image src attribute properly.

How can I do an inner loop for any images within the body once I have the body tag?

Thank you.

Comment: If it was a properly formed HTML document, there would be **NO** images outside of the body tag.

Comment: Uh, sidebars, headers, etc. are all within the body. You can't have images outside the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reverse two lines and rewrite a smidgen.

```
$mybody = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0);
$tags2 = $mybody->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

The reason is that the Body tag is actually a DOMElement instance of the class, and is able to perform the same call to `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: That makes sense but when I try to loop through foreach ($tags2 as $tag) { echo "image FOUND"; } doesn't show anything, both with the outer foreach loop and when commenting it out. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1108224 Are you looking for one image in specific? You could always assign it an ID, unless you're scraping a website. Because if there's an image contained within the `$mybody` element the code I gave ought to retrieve it.

Comment: I'm learning about scraping. I'm messing around with aggregating articles from news sites and just wanted to link to the main images and not their banners, twitter+social media icons, etc    I'll accept your answer as I know that works in DOM on websites for finding stuff within another element so it must be my implementation. I'll keep trying

Comment: @RobertK: Don't use `DOMNodeList`s as arrays, instead, use the `->item(0)` method to select the first element.

Comment: got it working :) Thanks so much. The image I want is inside paragraphs so I found the body, found p, then found the image within p.